# How to align sub figures more than 5 vertically in multi column using IEEEtrans class?

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

I am using the class IEEEtrans, so I have multi columns. As you can see in my output, the problem is that latex is placing all five sub figures in the same column, instead of placing the last sub figure that is fig:e on the next page. So as a result fig:e isn't fully appearing. Secondly, as you can see, the left column of my page is totally empty and I don't understand why latex isn't placing the first four figures i-e fig:a,b,c,d on left side and then fig:e on the right side and that is exactly what I want to do. Kindly help.

[image: That is my output]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font = footnotesize]{caption}
%\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=9.6cm,height=5.2cm]{a.JPG}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:a}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=9.6cm,height=5.2cm]{b.JPG}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:b}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=9.6cm,height=5.2cm]{c.JPG}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:c}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=9.6cm,height=5.2cm]{d.JPG}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:d}}
\end{subfigure}
%\vspace{20mm}
\begin{subfigure}[H]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=9.6cm,height=5.2cm]{e.JPG}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:e}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{FIG}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! you have to tall figure. You need to break it into two figures which for example the first one with two or three sub images is placed at bottom of column and second one with rest at top of the next column. Or make your images smaller.

Comment: To answer the question from a comment in the deleted answer, no, there is not way to split one float over two columns or pages.  You could create a macro to automatically create two floats if the subfigures exceed \textheight, or not use a float at all.

Comment: Only packages `graphicx` and `subcaption` are needed for the MWE.  There is no need to add `{\footnotesize ...}` in the caption.

Answer (score 2):

The `fakefigure` environment is not a float, but makes `\caption` and `subfigure` think they are in a `figure` environment.

I reduced the width of your images to the maximum allowed.  BTW, centering is pointless when the image fills the whole width, and captions are always centered (unless singlelinecheck=off).

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{fakefigure}{\par\vskip\textfloatsep% minimum separation
  \def\@captype{figure}%
  \parindent=0pt
  \parskip=0pt
  \textwidth=\columnwidth
  \clubpenalty0
  \widowpenalty0}%
  {\par\vskip\textfloatsep\vfil}%  helps with alignment
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{fakefigure}
\raggedbottom% esthetics

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:a}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:b}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:c}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:d}}
\end{subfigure}
%\vspace{20mm}
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
\centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1cm}
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}
\caption{{\footnotesize fig:e}}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{FIG}
\end{fakefigure}

\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Comment: nice solution! (+1). I would change definition for `fakefigure` to `\newenvironment{fakefigure}{
    \vspace{\baselineskip}%
    \def\@captype{figure}\raggedbottom}{\vfil}
\makeatother` or something similar which add some vertical space above (sub)figures.

Comment: @Zarko - Good idea, but used \textfloatsep instead of \baselineskip.

Comment: where I can find some description about `fakefigure` and `\textfloatsep`?

Comment: @Zarko - \textfloatsep and \@captype come from source2e.pdf which can be downloaded from CTAN.  As for fakefigure, what you see is what you get.